# TinyMCE Fortify Issue - Security Vulnerability - Open Redirect

Tags: javascript, security, tinymce, fortify

Fortify is flagging a 'Open Redirect' Issue in TinyMCE library we use for rich text editor

Below is the analysis evidence reported

Anyone know if this is a false positive?

```
 editor_plugin_src.js:69 - Read elm.value

 editor_plugin_src.js:69 - exec(0:return)

 editor_plugin_src.js:69 Assignment to matches

 editor_plugin_src.js:71 Assignment to data.docencoding

 editor_plugin_src.js:119 Return data

 editor_plugin_src.js:29 _htmlToData(return.docencoding)

 editor_plugin_src.js:29 Assignment to data

 editor_plugin_src.js:29 open(1)
```